# Question regarding linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we got $A:\ V \to W$ linear operator and let $\{w_1,w_2,....w_l\}$ be base for the Image of A ( ImA) . ( V,W are vector spaces ).Also let $v_1,v_2,....v_l\in V$ chosen so $A(v_i)=w_i$ for $i=1,2...l$. Now I have proved that $\{v_1,v_2,....v_l\}$ are linear independent and need to show that $V=[\{v_1,v_2,....v_l\}]\oplus Ker A$.

Supposing vector space $V$ is n-dimensional and  $\{v_1,v_2,...v_l,...v_n\}$ is a base for it. Is it true that $A(v_i)=0$ for $i=l+1,...n$ ? And if it is , does it require a proof ?

Comment: As far as I remember, this is *usually* done the other way around: you first begin with a basis of $\;\ker A\;$ , then you complete it to a basis of $\;V\;$ and show the image of the elements used to complete the basis are a basis for  Im$\,A\;$ . What are you trying to prove and why that way?

Comment: Also, you claim of $A(v_i)=0$ for $i>l$ is not true in general.

Comment: Well , I need to proove that $V=[\{v_1,v_2,....v_l\}]\oplus Ker A$.

Comment: May I use this way :
So we got $\{v_1,v_2,....v_l\}$ independent. By the rank/defect theorem , dim ( Ker A ) = $n-l$ . Creating $\{v_p,...v_n\}$ base for Ker A where p=$l$+1 , we can show that that none of $v_i$ ( $i=p,...n$) can be shown as linear combination of vectors : $v_j$( $j=1,...l$) using linear operator A. And using that , we can easily proove $\oplus$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say in your comment you need to prove, with your notation and definitions, is almost trivial since $\;M:=\text{Span}\,\{v_1,...,v_l\}\;,\;\;\ker A\;$ are subspaces of $\;V\;$ whose dimensions add to that of $\;n\;$, and thus their sum (as subspaces) is automatically direct...

Remember that for a vector space $\;U\;$ with subspaces $\;X,\,Y\;$ , the following conditions are equivalent:

$$\begin{align*}
&(1)\;\;U=X\oplus Y\\{}\\
&(2)\;\;U=X+Y\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;X\cap Y=\{0\}\\{}\\
&(3)\;\;\dim X+\dim Y=\dim U\\{}\\
&(4)\;\;\forall\,u\in U\;\;\exists!\,x_u\in X\,,\,y_u\in Y\;\;s.t.\;\; u= x_u+y_u\end{align*}$$